# Point in four dimensions

Tags: geometry

To describe a point in $3$D:

Three parameters $ r,\phi, \theta $ are used in spherical coordinate system.  Taking them pairwise,two as $(r, \theta)$ in azimuth plane and two $(r,\phi )$ in meridian plane.

Similarly to describe a point in $4D$ 4-space, can we describe 4-tuple parameters with known $3$D geometrical meanings for some of six intersections of $3$-space ?

EDIT 1:

I like to see a description where at least 3 of 6 possibilities is convincingly demonstrated.

Comment: Wouldn't we describe a point in $n$-space by an $n$-tuple: $(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$?

Comment: @Pacman The OP is probably asking for a coordinate system similar to the spherical coordincate system, not like the rectangular system.

Comment: @Arpan Something like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Hyperspherical_coordinates  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several coordinate systems which derive logically from the coordinate systems in lower dimension.

I'll give the coordinate systems labels which give a "grouping" of dimensions (I hope it will become clear what I mean; it's hard to explain before I show the coordinate systems).

## (1,1,1,1) — Cartesian coordinates

These are the most obvious choice of coordinates. Each coordinate gives the position on one of the four orthogonal axes. These coordinates are typically labelled $(x,y,z,w)$, and so will I.

Setting one coordinate constant describes a hyperplane (3-dimensional affine subspace) orthogonal to the corresponding axis; for example, setting $w=0$ gives the $x$-$y$-$z$ space.

Setting two of the coordinates constant describes a plane orthogonal to both corresponding axes; for example, setting $z=w=0$ gives the $x$-$y$ plane.

Setting three of the coordinates constant describes a line parallel to the remining coordinate's axis. For example, setting $y=z=w=0$ gives the $x$ axis.

## (2,1,1) — A generalization of cylinder coordinates

This is a natural extension of the cylinder coordinates in $3D$: We have one coordinate, which I'll call $r_{xy}$, that gives the distance from the $zw$ plane (that is, the radius of the projection into the $x$-$y$ plane), an angle $\phi_{xy}$ in the $x$-$y$ plane, and the remaining coordinates $z$ and $t$. They are related to the Cartesian coordinates by
$$\begin{align}
 x &= r_{xy} \cos\phi_{xy}\\
 y &= r_{xy} \sin\phi_{xy}\\
 z &= z\\
 w &= w
\end{align}$$

Setting $r_{xy}$ constant gives a sort of 4D cylinder around the $z$-$w$ plane, in the following sense: In 3D, a cylinder can be thought of as adding an orthogonal line to each point of a circle; in cylinder coordinates the circle is in the $x$-$y$ plane, and the lines are parallel to the $z$ axis. Similarly, this 4D cylinder is obtained by adding an orthogonal *plane* parallel to the $z$-$w$ plane to each point of the circle in the $x$-$y$ plane. Note that these planes are "completely orthogonal" to the $x$-$y$ plane in the sense that every direction on those planes is orthogonal to every direction in the $x$-$y$ plane. This is not possible in three dimensions, since there any two planes intersect in a line, that is, have a common direction. Note that in the case $r_{xy}=0$, that cylinder degenerated, and we get exactly the $z$-$w$ plane.

Setting $\phi_{xy}$ constant gives a half-hyperplane (three-dimensional half-space) starting at the $z$-$w$ plane and going away from it in the direction $\phi_{xy}$. That is again analogous to the three-dimensional case, where you have a half-plane starting at the $z$ axis and going away from it in the direction $\phi_{xy}$.

Setting $z$ or $w$ constant has, of course, the same effect as with Cartesian coordinates.

Setting both $r_{xy}$ and $\phi_{xy}$ constant has the same effect as setting $x$ and $y$ constant, since $r_{xy}$ and $\phi_xy}$ uniquely determine $x$ and $y$. Of course, setting both $z$ and $w$ constant also has the same effect as in Cartesian coordinates.

Since setting $w$ constant selects a $3$-dimensional hyperplane, in which the other coordinates just are cylinder coordinates, setting one of the other coordinates constant has the effect to select the corresponding subset of that 3D hyperspace. So both $w$ and $r$ constant select an ordinary 2D cylinder, and $w$ and $\phi$ constant selects a half-plane. Of course, having $z$ instead of $w$ constant doesn't qualitatively change anything.

Thus also the effect of setting three coordinates constant is obvious (I'm omitting combinations which are qualitatively equivalent to those given):

- $r_{xy}$, $\phi_{xy}$, $z$ constant gives a straight line parallel to $w$.
- $r_{xy}$, $z$, $w$ constant gives a circle with center on the $z$-$w$ plane.
- $\phi_{xy}$, $z$, $w$ constant gives a ray originating on the $z$-$w$ plane.

## (2,2) — "Toric coordinates"

This is a genuinely 4D coordinate system which has no obvious 3D equivalent. Basically, we introduce polar coordinates both on the $x$-$y$ and the $z$-$w$ plane, giving us the four coordinates $(r_{xy},\phi_{xy},r_{zw},\phi_{zw})$ (now it should be clear why I introduced the index before):
$$\begin{align}
 x &= r_{xy} \cos\phi_{xy}\\
 y &= r_{xy} \sin\phi_{xy}\\
 z &= r_{zw} \sin\phi_{zw}\\
 w &= r_{zw} \cos\phi_{zw}
\end{align}$$

Clearly there's a symmetry between coordinates $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$, which allows us to cut down the essentially different cases we need to consider. Moreover, the cases where only one of the coordinates is set constant is exactly equivalent to the case of setting $r_{xy}$ or $\phi_{xy}$ constant in the case (2,1,1). The same is true for setting both coordinates of one of the sets constant.

Setting $r_{xy}$ and $r_{zw}$ constant gives a "flat" torus, that is, a torus whose inner curvature vanishes (yet another thing that only exists in four dimensions). Setting $\phi_{xy}$ and $\phi_{wz}$ constant gives a quadrant of a plane selected by those two angles. Setting $r_{xy}$ and $\phi_{zw}$ constant gives a half-infinite cylinder of radious $r_{xy}$ going into a direction orthogonal to the $x$-$y$ plane determined by $\phi_{zw}$.

## (3,1) — Another generalization of cylinder coordinates.

Here we introduce spherical coordinates in the $x$-$y$-$z$ hyperplane (3D space) and add the $w$ coordinate:
$$\begin{align}
 x &= r_{xyz} \cos\theta \cos\phi\\
 y &= r_{xyz} \cos\theta \sin\phi\\
 z &= r_{xyz} \sin\theta\\
 w &= w
\end{align}$$

Obviously setting $w$ constant again selects a hyperplane parallel to the $x$-$y$-$z$ hyperplane, and setting any other single coordinate constant gives the result of setting that coordinate constant in 3D spherical coordinates and extruding into the fourth dimension. In particular, $r_{xyz}$ constant gives a spherical cylinder, $\theta$ constant gives an "extruded halfcone" and $\phi$ constant gives a half-hyperplane.

The analogue happens also for two coordinates fixed: If $w$ is among them, we get the normal 3D results (sphere, halfcone, halfplane) embedded in 4 space, otherwise we get an extruded version of the result of setting the two variables fixed in spherical coordinates (that is, spherical cylinders or halfplanes). Similar for three coordinates (including $w$: circle, ray; not including $w$: straight line parallel to $w$ axis)

## (4) — "Hyperspherical coordinates"

This is the straightforward generalization of spherical coordinates to 4D:
$$\begin{align}
 x &= r \cos\eta \cos\theta \cos\phi\\
 y &= r \cos\eta \cos\theta \sin\phi\\
 z &= r \cos\eta \sin\theta\\
 w &= r \sin\eta
\end{align}$$

A constant $r$ gives a hypersphere ($^3S$, 3D surface that is the 4D equivalent of the 2D sphere in 3D). A constant $\eta$ gives a sort of spherical hypercone. For constant $\theta$ this gives some complicated shape which I'm currently not able to imageine, and for constant $\phi$ this gives a half-hyperplane.

Determining the shapes for more variables constant is now too complicated for me, especially that here it's already past midnight. ;-)

Comment: Thank much @celtchk, for so elaborately answering my question.. that  helps entering into the fourth (linear) dimension.

Answer (score 0):

For the coordinate systems in 4 dimensions, there are no other common coordinate systems, assuming you only use copy extrusion (extra Cartesian coordinate / length coordinate) and revolution (extra angle for polar coordinates) besides these 5 systems. This is because the number 4 can be grouped into 5 groups: (1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), and (4), assuming order doesn't matter. Also, you can derive these coordinate systems from their 3D counterparts: Assuming you have Cartesian 3D coordinates, you could copy extrude to get 4D Cartesian, or you could rotate it to get the cubindrical [(2, 1, 1)] coordinate system. Copy extrusion adds a 1 to the right of the group, while rotation increments the furthest left number by 1, assuming you are rotating about the main plane of rotation. Therefore, with cylindrical coordinates, you could make both cubindrical [(2, 1, 1)] and spherindrical [(3, 1)] coordinates, and with spherical coordinates, you could make spherindrical [(3, 1)] and hyperspherical coordinates using this formula. For toric coordinates, which I like to call "double-polar coordinates", it is pretty unique, as it is a result from a double-revolution from 2D, as a 4D torus (when $r_{xy}$ and $r_{zw}$ are constant), could be considered as a circle with 2 radii, which is a result when you doubly rotate a circle about the $zw$-plane, which is more complex than the rotation about an axis we are used to. Finally, if we don't use these extrusion limits, theoretically, there are infinite number of coordinate systems in 4D (or any number of dimensions) using the Jacobian transformation, where $J$ is equal to $\frac{\partial(x, y, z, w)}{\partial(s, t, u, v)}$, which is equal to the 4x4 variant of the Jacobian matrix. Using this, we could derive the differentials for the volumes in 4D for all 5 of these coordinate systems:
Cartesian coordinates: Simple. $dxdydzdw$. Most people would want to evaluate the quadruple integral starting from w, so $dwdzdydx$. There are 24 ways to arrange the differentials in a quadruple integral, so choose one that is easy to evaluate. Integral of a unit tesseract: $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1dwdzdydx$, which is obviously 1 unit$^4$.
Cubindrical coordinates: Also quite easy. $r_{xy}dr_{xy}d\theta dzdw$, as the r residual comes from the Jacobian matrix for polar coordinates in 2D. Integral of a unit cubilinder: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1r_{xy}dwdzdr_{xy} d\theta$ = $\pi$ units$^4$.
Spherindrical coordinates: Moderate. $r_{xyz}^2\sin(\phi)dr_{xyz}d\phi d\theta dw$. Integral of a unit spherilinder: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^1r_{xyz}^2\sin(\phi)dwdr_{xyz}d\phi d\theta$ = $\frac{4}{3}\pi$ units$^4$.
Hyperspherical coordinates: Hard. Using the Jacobian matrix, we can determine that the differential for 4D volume is $r^3\sin^2(\phi)\sin(\psi)drd\phi d\psi d\theta$. Integral of a hypersphere of radius R: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^Rr^3\sin^2(\phi)\sin(\psi)drd\phi d\psi d\theta$ = $\frac{\pi^2 R^4}{2}$
Toric coordinates: Easier. $r_{xy}r_{zw}dr_{xy}d\theta_{xy}dr_{zw}d\theta_{zw}$. Integral of a torus of radii of 1 and 1: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1r_{xy}r_{zw}dr_{zw}d\theta_{zw} dr_{xy} d\theta_{xy}$ = $\pi^2$ units$^4$. Also, the formulas for moments of inertia on a cell (3D space) could be given with this formula: $M_{xyz} = \rho wdV$ where dV is the 4D volume differential, $\rho$ is the density function, and M is the moment of inertia on the xyz-cell. Other moments of inertia of higher order can be derived using the square and orthogonal rule, and the centers of mass can be derived with the ratio of the moments of inertia and the mass function of $\rho dV$.